# Изменение вертикальной прокрутки на горизонтальную в точке для определенного элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

**Каков контекст проблемы?**

У меня есть веб-сайт, представляющий собой одну страницу, на которой я буду представлять свою деятельность и проекты. После прокрутки нескольких разделов у нас есть проекты подряд.

**Что я хочу сделать ?**

Я хочу поменять вертикальную прокрутку на горизонтальную, когда мы дойдем до горизонтальной строки моих проектов. Когда вы находитесь в конце ряда, он просто должен вернуться в нормальное состояние с помощью вертикальной прокрутки.

**Код**

```
<div className="projectsContainer">     // <--- высота 100vh
    <div className="row projects">     //  <--- Расположен посередине родителя ↑
        <project1  />
        <project2  />
        <project3  />
        <project4  />
        <project5  />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Вот мой код. И что я делал**

У меня есть метод `inTheMiddle()`, который является логическим. Если `<div className="row projects">` находится в середине области просмотра, он возвращает `true`, иначе `false`.

Метод `scrollDirection()`, который также является логическим, `true`, когда прокрутка идет вниз, `false`, когда она идет вверх.

Есть Множество различных методов `disableScroll()` Последний метод disableScroll() отменяет прокрутку, пересчитывая ее.

```
componentDidMount() {
     window.addEventListener('wheel', (this.handleScroll));
}
...
disableScroll() {
    // Get the current page scroll position 
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    // if any scroll is attempted, set this to the previous value 
    window.onscroll = () => {
        window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
    };
}
```

И ещё мой метод `handleScroll()`, который управляет всем этим

```
handleScroll(event) {
    const rowProjects = document.querySelector(".row.projects")
    const projectsContainer = document.querySelector(".projectsContainer")
    const isSticky = rowProjects.classList.contains("sticky") 
// isSticky is useless now was try by adding position fixed and no need to use disableScroll()

    if (this.inTheMiddle() && this.state.scrollDown && this.state.count < 1400 ) {
        this.disableScroll()
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 10 })
        rowProjects.scroll(this.state.count, 0)
    } else if ((!this.state.scrollDown) && this.state.count > 0) {
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 10 })
        rowProjects.scroll(this.state.count, 0)
    }

}
```

Чего я не могу сделать, так это вернуться к нормальному состоянию прокрутки. Когда вы достигаете конца строки, я не могу повторно включить прокрутку,  когда я прокручиваю страницу вверх. Он застрял в строке проектов.

Я справился с этим с помощью `isSticky`. Я удалил `disableScroll()` и добавил класс с фиксированной позицией, но проблема заключалась в том, что он отскочил. Потому что, когда он находится посередине, я зафиксировался в середине области просмотра, поэтому элемент больше не находится в относительном положении, поэтому он подпрыгнул, как сбой (например, сняв блокировку блока стека), извините за плохой пример :')

Если у вас есть идея помочь мне, это было бы очень любезно. Ломаю голову уже 3 дня и так и не нашел идеального решения.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Changing vertical scroll to horizontal at a point for a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63996962/7394871) от участника  [@crg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7942242/crg).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63996962/7394871

Comment: Такие ухищрения, чтобы сделать безобразный эффект, за который дизайнерам сайтов надо отбивать руки...

Comment: @Инквизитор ничего безобразного не вижу. Вариант имеет право на жизнь. Сначала вертикальная прокрутка, потом горизонтальная прокрутка и снова вертикальная. Впрочем у каждого свои вкусы, фломастеры.

Answer (score 0):

Это должно работать нормально. Вы можете выполнить вертикальную прокрутку и использовать значение `window.scrollY` для смещения элемента по горизонтали, назначив его значение в `element.style.left`, тем самым придав ему эффект горизонтальной прокрутки. Я сделал то же самое, и это сработало.

### (См. результат в полноэкранном режиме).

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content_2');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scrolledY = window.scrollY;
  var scrolledX = window.scrollX;

  if (scrolledY > 625 && scrolledY < 3112) {
    content.style.marginTop = 150 + 'px';
    content.style.position = "fixed";
    content.style.top = scrolledY * 0.001 + 'px';
    content.style.left = -(scrolledY - 625) * 0.55 + 'px';

  }
  if (scrolledY <= 625) {
    content.style.position = "initial";

  }
  if (scrolledY >= 3112) {

    content.style.position = "absolute";
    content.style.top = 3112 + 'px';

  }


});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  min-height: 4400px;
}

.content_1,
.content_2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.content_1 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.content_1 h1 {
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content_2 {
  margin-top: 150px;
  top: 625px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 200vw;
  position: fixed;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.content_3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 3050px;
}

.card {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_1">
  <h1>First Page</h1>
</div>
<div class="content_2" id="content_2">
  <div class="card" style="background-color: #FF7A7A;">Card-1</div>
  <div class="card" style="background-color: #FF3C3C;">Card-2</div>
  <div class="card">Card-3</div>
  <div class="card" style="background-color: #FF3600;">Card-4</div>
  <div class="card" style="background-color: #FF871C;">Card-5</div>
  <div class="card" style="background-color: #FFA91C;">Card-6</div>
  <div class="card" style="background-color: #FFC11D;">Card-7</div>
  <div class="card" style="background-color: #FFF81D;">Card-8</div>
</div>
<div class="content_3">
  <p>Senectus purus, molestie blandit sociis eu leo blandit platea commodo aptent scelerisque cursus. Hac vel himenaeos hendrerit eu pellentesque. Lorem natoque praesent dictum porta, aliquam bibendum laoreet class litora? Class nullam maecenas aliquet.
    Ligula, et enim vel rutrum luctus lorem orci fringilla in erat? Bibendum magnis nec volutpat non netus dignissim. Tempus tempor penatibus nulla egestas semper scelerisque cubilia. Nulla adipiscing per porta consequat et imperdiet posuere magna fringilla
    rhoncus conubia. Sapien proin euismod.
  </p>
  <p>Tempus luctus tempor donec pretium lectus leo facilisis leo, inceptos nostra lorem vel. Orci parturient urna etiam pharetra sit lacus volutpat id sed lacinia. Scelerisque ultrices nisi risus aenean tincidunt, amet arcu tempus id curabitur purus fringilla.
    Eros iaculis vitae vitae rutrum ultricies dolor sociis ante ante ut. Ut nibh primis himenaeos egestas dictumst congue scelerisque!
  </p>
  <p>Blandit sociis quisque ultrices montes tortor. Penatibus risus primis, senectus nam nostra. Egestas, nulla vitae penatibus cursus sed. Luctus, eget dignissim porttitor et curae; accumsan. Accumsan blandit ligula sollicitudin. Ligula mattis ad turpis
    arcu mus laoreet conubia risus accumsan quis lobortis. Nisi sollicitudin penatibus lacus nam justo id commodo sagittis. Leo orci.
  </p>

  <p>Fringilla sociosqu laoreet id, dui lobortis condimentum? Facilisis non, cubilia diam. Egestas aptent ornare et felis morbi senectus molestie, egestas donec himenaeos ultrices himenaeos. Condimentum conubia nisl urna lobortis pharetra adipiscing cras
    eget pellentesque sollicitudin faucibus. Scelerisque lobortis nascetur neque ac quam dignissim fames. Magnis pharetra dignissim nullam sapien eu curabitur, ridiculus dapibus. Aptent tempus nibh eget scelerisque magna ipsum turpis. Taciti nostra morbi
    pharetra montes sagittis posuere mollis.
  </p>
  <p>Taciti tortor phasellus placerat inceptos tristique consectetur accumsan vitae potenti sodales nulla eros. Dapibus scelerisque penatibus nisl accumsan ultricies ridiculus porta. Varius tellus erat laoreet morbi tempor tristique. Sapien, sem morbi libero
    dapibus curabitur. Facilisi habitasse feugiat semper magnis risus id tellus libero semper. Vehicula turpis elit lectus interdum metus ultrices mollis consectetur cubilia.
  </p>
  <p>Senectus purus, molestie blandit sociis eu leo blandit platea commodo aptent scelerisque cursus. Hac vel himenaeos hendrerit eu pellentesque. Lorem natoque praesent dictum porta, aliquam bibendum laoreet class litora? Class nullam maecenas aliquet.
    Ligula, et enim vel rutrum luctus lorem orci fringilla in erat? Bibendum magnis nec volutpat non netus dignissim. Tempus tempor penatibus nulla egestas semper scelerisque cubilia. Nulla adipiscing per porta consequat et imperdiet posuere magna fringilla
    rhoncus conubia. Sapien proin euismod.
  </p>

  <p>Tempus luctus tempor donec pretium lectus leo facilisis leo, inceptos nostra lorem vel. Orci parturient urna etiam pharetra sit lacus volutpat id sed lacinia. Scelerisque ultrices nisi risus aenean tincidunt, amet arcu tempus id curabitur purus fringilla.
    Eros iaculis vitae vitae rutrum ultricies dolor sociis ante ante ut. Ut nibh primis himenaeos egestas dictumst congue scelerisque!
  </p>
  <p>Blandit sociis quisque ultrices montes tortor. Penatibus risus primis, senectus nam nostra. Egestas, nulla vitae penatibus cursus sed. Luctus, eget dignissim porttitor et curae; accumsan. Accumsan blandit ligula sollicitudin. Ligula mattis ad turpis
    arcu mus laoreet conubia risus accumsan quis lobortis. Nisi sollicitudin penatibus lacus nam justo id commodo sagittis. Leo orci.
  </p>
  <p>Fringilla sociosqu laoreet id, dui lobortis condimentum? Facilisis non, cubilia diam. Egestas aptent ornare et felis morbi senectus molestie, egestas donec himenaeos ultrices himenaeos. Condimentum conubia nisl urna lobortis pharetra adipiscing cras
    eget pellentesque sollicitudin faucibus. Scelerisque lobortis nascetur neque ac quam dignissim fames. Magnis pharetra dignissim nullam sapien eu curabitur, ridiculus dapibus. Aptent tempus nibh eget scelerisque magna ipsum turpis. Taciti nostra morbi
    pharetra montes sagittis posuere mollis.
  </p>
  <p>Taciti tortor phasellus placerat inceptos tristique consectetur accumsan vitae potenti sodales nulla eros. Dapibus scelerisque penatibus nisl accumsan ultricies ridiculus porta. Varius tellus erat laoreet morbi tempor tristique. Sapien, sem morbi libero
    dapibus curabitur. Facilisi habitasse feugiat semper magnis risus id tellus libero semper. Vehicula turpis elit lectus interdum metus ultrices mollis consectetur cubilia.
  </p>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64166452/7394871) от участника  [@Ac_mmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14225299/ac-mmi).</sub>